# How to convert my C# code into a mathematical formula

Tags: c#, math, formula, discrete-mathematics

How can I convert my C# code into a mathematical formula? I would like to use discrete mathematics and convert my code into a mathematical formula.

Here is the example C# code that I have written. The aim is to calculate a rank based on the positive and negative weight that is assigned to each variable. The positive weight is added to the rank if the variable is higher than 0. The negative weight is taken away from the rank if the variable is a negative number.

```
var aPosWeight = 3;
var aNegativeWeight = -3;

var bPosWeight = 2;
var bNegativeWeight = -2;

var cPosWeight = 1;
var cNegativeWeight = -1;

var a = 1;
var b = 0;
var c = -1;

var rank = 0;


if (a > 0)
{
    rank += aPosWeight;
}
else if (a < 0)
{
    rank += aNegativeWeight;
}

if (b > 0)
{
    rank += bPosWeight;
}
else if (b < 0)
{
    rank += bNegativeWeight;
}

if (c > 0)
{
    rank += cPosWeight;
}
else if (c < 0)
{
    rank += cNegativeWeight;
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Your final rank is {0}", rank));
```

Here is the mathematical formula that I have come up with that I think represents the C# code written above. My main concern is that the mathematical formula is completely wrong and can't be used to interpret the C# code that I've written above.

[image: Mathematical formula]

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming, but instead how to translate a set of criteria into a mathematical expression/function.

Comment: Where should I post my question?

Answer (score 1):

[image: I think this is what you want]

Please note that sgn function description below:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function

you code takes no action for "zero" items, so I assumed that they do not affect r, because sgn(0) = 0.